# How to control the panel of MainForm using UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
MainForm myMainForm;

private void ButtonResort_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    panelSub.Controls.Add(new myUserControl());
}
```

After adding my myUserControl to my MainForm. How can I add my myUserControl2 to other panel of my MainForm?

```
public partial class myUserControl : UserControl
{
    MainForm myMainForm;

    public myUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        myMainForm.PanelBody.Controls.Add(new myUserControl2());
    }
}
```

this is the code I've tried and it just gives me an error.
"Object Reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Is it Winform application?

Comment: Yes it is a Winform application.

Comment: Edited my post and put there the code I've tried to use.

Comment: You need to find form on which your user control sits and assign reference to `myMainForm`. At this time, when you do `myMainForm.PanelBody.Controls.Add(new myUserControl2());` your  `myMainForm` in not initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `myMainForm` has never been set

You can set it in your `myUserControl` constructor

```
public partial class myUserControl : UserControl
{
    MainForm myMainForm;

    public myUserControl(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myMainForm = mainForm;
    }

    private void Button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        myMainForm.PanelBody.Controls.Add(new myUserControl2());
    }
}
```

Usage

```
panelSub.Controls.Add(new myUserControl(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative way to passing form in constructor, you can do this:

```
private void Button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    myMainForm = this.FindForm as MainForm;
    if (myMainForm != null)
        myMainForm.PanelBody.Controls.Add(new myUserControl2());
}
```

If you interested in reusability, you pass `form` or `control` in constructor. Form is also derivative of control btw. Same thing with `FindForm`. If you mention `MainForm` - it is tightly coupled. If you use `form` - it could be any form. Usually, people pass actual surface [control] on which to add your new control.